# Can I dynamically count the number of times I reset an Excel Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a reset button for my excel sheet which will clear the contents except the formulas I have. Is there a way to dynamically count how many times I "pressed" the reset button and clear contents?

Comment: Yes. Store the number in a cell on a hidden worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This..

```
Public countR As Long
Sub Alternative1() 'This will return to 0 when you close the workbook
    countR = countR + 1
    MsgBox "The document has been cleared " & countR & " time(s)"
End Sub
```

or..

```
Sub Alternative2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1") 'Change to some cell that isn't cleared by your code
    rng.Value = rng.Value + 1
End Sub
```

and call them like..

```
Sub WhatYourCodeMaybeLooksLike()
    Range("B1:C100").ClearContents
    Alternative1
    Alternative2
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you @AsUsual it helped and it worked, I ended up doing it this way, truly grateful

Answer (score 0):

The comment by reportgunner above is correct, but if you're asking for VBA options then look at module level variables.

`Public x As Integer
Sub Button1_Click()
    x = x + 1
    MsgBox x
End Sub`

`x` will begin as 0 when you open the workbook and will then be incremented each time Button1 is hit, in this case.

Slightly different are static variables which you can declare in the procedure with the code. Both will work fine in VBA.

The variable will often reset if your code hits errors during debugging. So the cell option might be preferable if you never want to lose track of the number.